# Obtain Java Class name from QName

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

Suppose you have a QName that represents a type in an .xsd document.  How can I find out the name of the class that it would unmarshal into?

For example, I've got a QName: `{http://www.domain.com/service/things.xsd}customer`

This gets unmarshalled into a `com.domain.service.things.Customer`.

Is there a way I can do this without parsing the QName string representation?

Edit:

I've got a some .xsd's defined that are being used to create Java classes.  I want to select one of these Java classes dynamically based on a QName that is being passed in as a String on an HTML form.

Edit2:

Since these classes' names are being automatically generated, somewhere there must be a method that generates their names from a QName.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail about what you are trying to do? Without knowing more, I would have said, just use xjc (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/jaxb/xjc.html) to compile the XML to java and see the code. But I am sure there is more to this than the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could leverage the JAXBInstropector and do the following:

```
package example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBIntrospector;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class[] classes = new Class[3];
        classes[0] = A.class;
        classes[1] = B.class;
        classes[2] = C.class;

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(classes);

        JAXBIntrospector ji = jc.createJAXBIntrospector();
        Map<QName, Class> classByQName = new HashMap<QName, Class>(classes.length);
        for(Class clazz : classes) {
            QName qName = ji.getElementName(clazz.newInstance());
            if(null != qName) {
                classByQName.put(qName, clazz);
            }
        }

        QName qName = new QName("http://www.example.com", "EH");
        System.out.println(classByQName.get(qName));
    }

}
```

The following are the model classes:

**A**

```
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="EH", namespace="http://www.example.com")
public class A {
}
```

**B**

```
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="BEE", namespace="urn:example")
public class B {
}
```

**C**

```
package example;

public class C {
}
```

**Output**

```
class example.A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String getClassName(final QName qName) {
    final String clazz = WordUtils.capitalize(qName.getLocalPart());
    final String ns = qName.getNamespaceURI();

    String s = ns.replace("http://", "");
    s = s.replace("www.", "");
    s = s.replace(".xsd", "");
    s = s.replace("/", ".");
    final String tld = s.split(".")[1];
    s = s.replace("." + tld, "");

    return tld + "." + s + "." + clazz;
}
```

Comment: You also need to guard against your algorithm producing a class name with invalid characters.  A full algorithm is included in the JAXB specification (JSR-222).