# JAXB how to get QName based on java object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

We are using maven plugin to generate a large number of Java pojos and ObjectFactory, similar to:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ProtectedABC", propOrder = {
    "aBC"
})
public class ABC {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String aBC;

   
    public String getABC() {
        return aBC;
    }

    
    public void setABC(String value) {
        this.aBC= value;
    }

}
```

and

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName ABC = new QName("http://www", "request1");
    private final static QName DEF = new QName("http://www", "response1");
    private final static QName XYZ = new QName("http://www", "result1");
    /*
     * A LOT OF QNAMES HERE
     */
    private final static QName END = new QName("http://www", "end");
  
    //OTHER GENERATED METHODS
}
```

I have a method that take a java object (value) and I need to convert it to JaxbElement

```
  public DataBuffer encodeValue(Object value, DataBufferFactory bufferFactory, ResolvableType valueType, @Nullable MimeType mimeType, @Nullable Map<String, Object> hints) {
    boolean release = true;
    DataBuffer buffer = bufferFactory.allocateBuffer(1024);
    try {
      OutputStream outputStream = buffer.asOutputStream();
      Class<?> clazz = ClassUtils.getUserClass(value);
      
      JAXBContext jaxbContext = JaxbUtils.createJaxbContext();
      Marshaller marshaller = initMarshaller(jaxbContext);
      JAXBIntrospector jaxbIntrospector = jaxbContext.createJAXBIntrospector();

      //HERE I TRY TO GET QNAME BASED ON POJO:
      //BASED ON THIS POST: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035716/obtain-java-class-name-from-qname
      QName elementName = jaxbIntrospector.getElementName(value);

      JAXBElement<Object> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement(elementName , clazz, value);
      marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, outputStream);
      release = false;
      return buffer;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      throw new EncodingException("Could not marshal " + value.getClass() + " to XML", ex);
    }
  }
```

The problem is `QName elementName = jaxbIntrospector.getElementName(value);` return null so I cannot create JAXBElement. I don't want to check type/class of `value` like `if(value instance of ABC) {}` since I have a huge number of pojos. Please tell me is it possible to get/obtain QName based on a java object (do not know exactly its type)?

NOTE: I have found a method `((JAXBContextImpl) jaxbContext).getTypeName(TypeReference)` that take a TypeReference and return QName, but I do'nt know how to construct TypeReference, too.

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score -1):

I dont think you should create JAXElement from scratch with  `new JAXBElement(elementName , clazz, value)`

In ObjectFactory, we can create JAXElement directly via method starting with `createSomething()` - and the newly-created JAXElement will have QName for itself. So my approach is:

1. Get the name of class for the value object that should be converted -> by ClassUtils in spring core or something like that
2. Add `create` before the name we already get in step1
3. Initialize an instance of ObjectFactory and invoke method `createSomething(value)` with Reflection lib (of course dont forget catch exception in case there is no supported method in ObjectFactory!)

Hope it help and if possible, please give me a look of your schema files (xsd or wsdl, etc) or your classes which are generated from schema files, so that I can elaborate on those for detailed lines of code.